# How to invoke a SQL Server stored procedure with entity returns in EF 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am seeing examples which appear to depend upon EF 6, for instance. Non starter since I am targeting .NET Core v3.1 for the time being.

If necessary, I can look into later core versions, I suppose, but for now it is what it is.

Is it possible to invoke a stored procedure from EF5? I am not finding ways to do this, yet, or the .NET API is not what I would expect.

Can someone offer some insight here? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have tried or what kind of stored procedure you are tyring to execute but I think in EF 5 it is

If you have a DbSet this returns IQueryable

```
Context.Database.DbSet<T>.FromSqlRaw(string sql, params object[] parameters)
```

From the Database itself it would be but this only returns number of rows affected

```
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(string sql, params object[] parameters)
```

Where the sql string is something like "EXECUTE dbo.ProcName"

There is also ExecuteSqlInterpolated it only returns the number of rows affected as well.